# Как сделать scrollView снизу прозрачным?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать scrollView снизу таким как я отметил на изображении? Немного прозрачным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это RecyclerView/

Можно попробовать аттрибут  `requiresFadingEdge`

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"


android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
```

Есть еще библиотеки типа [Этой](https://github.com/bosphere/Android-FadingEdgeLayout)

Как вариант с просторов интернета

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
 android:theme="@style/RecyclerTheme"
 android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />


<style name="RecyclerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorGreen</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

 </style>
```